# upload a multi level rows and columns excel table into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, multilevel-analysis

I have a multi column/row spreadsheet.

```
The first column level is = date1, date2, date3.
The second column level is sex: male, female.
```

Hence the total is equal to 6 columns

```
date1,  date2,   date3
M, F    M, F     M, F
```

now, the table has also has multi level rows.
I have countries and and cities within each country.

How can I import this pre-made excel table into a pandas dataframe?
Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Please post data and the code that you already tried.

Comment: I can't because it's in my company PC. and to make my problem even worst is that in reality I have 3 level of rows. Country, State, City. :(